# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Doctrine\ORM\Configuration::setSchemaIgnoreClasses()

Tags: symfony, symfony5.4

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Doctrine\ORM\Configuration::setSchemaIgnoreClasses() in /var/cache/prod/ContainerEFlduTO/getDoctrine_Orm_DefaultEntityManagerService.php:65

I get this error on composer require command. If anyone has a solution, I would be very happy.

Comment: Sometimes deleting the cache directory `rm -r var/cache/prod` can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your composer version match with symfony version.
If you are using latest version of symfony use composer 2.0 using older or lts symfony use composer 1.*;

also try to clear cache after execution make migration.

```
symfony console cache:clear
```